# Find n from Ackermann function

Tags: logic, discrete-mathematics

I'm trying to solve the following problem : What is the largest value of n for which A(2,n) can be represented as a 37-bit unsigned integer?

I know the following are true for Ackermann function :

```
A(0,n) = n+1
A(m,0) = A(m-1,1)
A(m,n) = A(m-1, A(m,n-1))
```

How do I go from here ? Looks like without knowing n the equation becomes very long

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compute `A(2,n)` for a few values of `n`; it grows pretty fast, so it shouldn't take many to get a big enough value.